# How to Fix angular.min.js:108 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error is showing Angular js pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, pagination

i am new angularJs now and doing task of pagination, using simplePagination  library  for doing this stuff every thing configured and working fine but here when inspect Element in browser it is showing

```
 angular.min.js:108 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at b.$scope.numberOfPages (demoController.js:22)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:212), <anonymous>:4:230)
    at Object.get (angular.min.js:116)
    at n.$digest (angular.min.js:132)
    at n.$apply (angular.min.js:135)
    at l (angular.min.js:87)
    at F (angular.min.js:91)
```

Like this here i am using model one is service and controller demo.service

```
demoService.getTxn = function(scope) {
        $http.get(Commerce.root + '/user/getaccount').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            scope.inProgress = false;   
           scope.getname = data.nameList.length != 0 ? data.nameList : false;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            displayMessage(scope, Commerce.message.serverCommunicationError);
        });
    }
```

and controller code is

demo.Controller

```
 $scope.currentUser = Commerce.User;
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.currentPageOrders = 0;
    $scope.pageSizeOrders = 10;


    $scope.initUsers = function() {
        $scope.inProgress = true;
        demoService.getTxn($scope);
    }

    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.getTxn.length/$scope.pageSize);
    }
```

please help me to fix this issue .

Answer (score 0):

as the error says your getTxn array is undefined. You can initialize it to avoid undefined error.

```
$scope.currentUser = Commerce.User;
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 10;
$scope.currentPageOrders = 0;
$scope.pageSizeOrders = 10;
$scope.getTxn = [];


$scope.initUsers = function() {
    $scope.inProgress = true;
    demoService.getTxn($scope);
}

$scope.numberOfPages=function(){
    return Math.ceil($scope.getTxn.length/$scope.pageSize);
}
```

Comment: now that  error went out but what is happning in ui is --Previous 1/0 Next --- is showing it should show --previous 1/24 Next----
<button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
        Previous
    </button>
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= getTxn.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
        Next
    </button>
    </div>

Comment: You are seeing numberOfPages value 0 because it is empty. You need to set the value of getTxn somewhere in your code.

Comment: it is dynamic one i can't set it for particular value is there any way to do this means how to set it

Comment: by dynamic I assume you mean it is coming from some http request or loaded from file or something similar. If it is the case please set the value of array when you receive data. if you can provide a plunker I can further help you.